# Powerline Ethernet Slow Speed

Tags: networking, powerline-networking, wired-networking

I have three TP-Link AV500 powerline adapters set up to connect two desktops in different rooms to the router, which is downstairs. Over a direct wired connection, without the adapters but straight to the router, each PC is able to reach my 75 Mbps subscribed speed. However, when plugged into the adapters, they can each only reach around 30 Mbps when connected at the same time, and usually 60ish Mbps if only one is on. I was curious if the computers are sharing the one LAN port on the router that the router-side adapter is connected to, and thus splitting the connection. Is there a way to fix this? Or is this just how adapters work?

Comment: What speeds does the TP-Link powerline management app show? Powerline is like Wi-Fi in that it's very sensitive to environment, and the link adjusts accordingly.

Comment: And ... yes, if the router and the adapter are connected via one cable, then obviously the total speed is limited to that single port. But that's only an issue if both computers are trying to download stuff *at the same time* – it's not a reservation.

Comment: `HomePlug AV`is significantly slower than `HomePlug AV2` with a peak date rate of only `200 Mbps` vs `500-550 Mbps` with AV2.  You have created a bottlekneck by using the powerline adapters.  The adapters you have also only have 10/100 port instead of the 10/100/1000 port your router and PCs likely have.